# How to cast an object array to an arbitrary contenttype T (Object[] -> T[])

Tags: java, arrays, casting, stream, content-type

I wanna make my own Java streams to easily parse some strings. But I can't convert an object array to a T-array.

What I have already tried:

```
//  T[]  <-       Object[] 
    arr = (T[]) cache.toArray();
```

and

```
    T[] a = new T[6]; // Cannot create a generic array of T
    int index = 0;
    for (T i : arr) {
     a[++index] = i;
    }
```

Code:

```
public StreamParser<T> forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        ArrayList<T> cache = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T i : arr) {
            action.accept(i);
            cache.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(arr instanceof String[]);
        arr = (T[]) cache.toArray();
        System.out.println(arr instanceof String[]);
        return this;
    }
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: you are casting to T[] and then checking if it's an instance of String[] ... does T match String?

Comment: Yes, i did: String[] out = new StreamParser<String>()
    .of(str)
    .match("'(.*?)'")
    .parseToArray("[", ":", "]")
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e))
    .getArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList.toArray()` always returns exactly `Object[]`, never some subtype.

For this to work, you need to pass in a `T[]` or `IntFunction<T[]>` as a parameter (either to the constructor of `StreamParser`, or to the method), and use this in the `toArray()` call:

```
arr = cache.toArray(someIntFn.apply(0 /* or cache.size() */));
// Or
arr = cache.toArray(someArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the second method toArray taking an extra parameter.
Here are the javadoc link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29

Regarding the creating of a generic array, here is the trick required to do it:

```
public static <T> T[] genArray(Class<T> clazz, int size){
    return (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
}
```

that means an extra step to perform for which you need to have the actual class matching that `T` parameter